# Natural number coping sting to array

Tags: java, string, compare, instantiation, string-comparison

```
public class NaturalNumber 
{
int[] data = {};

private int toInt(char c)
{
    return (int)c - (int)'0';////converses a digit character to its integer value
}
```

I want to store the digits from `initData` as an integer in array data. I tried this but doesn't work.

```
public NaturalNumber(String initData)
{
    int[]data =new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    data[i] =Character.digit(initData.charAt(i), 10);}


/**compare this to other number and find out which one bigger or are they equal*/

public int compareTo(NaturalNumber other)
{

}


/**I want to set digitIndex between 0 and data.length - 1 and value to between 0 and 9*/


public void setDigit(int digitIndex, int value)
{
    digitIndex=Math.max(0,data.length-1);
    value=Math.max(0,9);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NaturalNumber(String initData)` constructor has issues with indexes going out of bounds e.g.:

```
public static class NaturalNumber {

    private int[] data;

    public NaturalNumber(String initData) {
        final int length = initData.length();
        data = new int[length]; // now we should have enough space
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            // Also there won't be any mismatch in size between 
            // initData and the maximum value for i so you don't
            // risk getting a IndexOutOfBoundsException
            data[i] = toInt(initData.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    private static int toInt(char c)
    {
        return (int)c - (int)'0'; // converts a digit character to its integer value
    }

    // possible implementation of compareTo
    public int compareTo(NaturalNumber that) {
        final int length = this.data.length;
        if(length != that.data.length) {
            return Integer.compare(length, that.data.length);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(this.data[i] != that.data[i]) {
                return Integer.compare(this.data[i], that.data[i]);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void setDigit(int index, int value) {
        if(value < 0 || value > 9) {
            return;
        }
        if(index < 0 || index > data.length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        data[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @doge47 I noticed I had a few typos in the `constructor` =] I've updated my answer with those bugs fixed.

Comment: in the constructor initData is a String containing the digits of this NaturalNumber so i have to instantiate the data array to correct size and store the digits from initData as an integer in array data. The constructor should use its setter to set each digit to

Comment: and the validation for setters are  digitIndex must be between 0 and data.length - 1 AND value must be between 0 and 9 otherwise the setter should not do anything to the data array.

Comment: @doge47 I've updated my answer to address the changes you mentioned. Check it out and let me know if you have any other question.